# C#: How to save a dictionary to a text file?

Tags: c#, string, text, dictionary, save

I've read up everywhere and cannot figure out how to save a dictionary to a .txt file. I know you can't just save the dictionary, you need to convert it to a string but I'm stuck at that. I have no idea how to convert it to a string, write it, then later read it back in and convert it from a string to a dictionary.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking up serialization. You could serialize your Dictionary to binary and store that in a file. See the [BinaryFormatter on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx). Simply, you could:

```
var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, dict);
```

There's also an [XmlSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the BinaryFormatter thing. I am now using a Hashtable instead of a dictionary and it works. It writes to a file.